# how to lock the column in adf?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-adf

I have oracle adf and jdeveloper.
I drag a table with 2 columns from datacontrol into jsf page.
column1 is a input text and column 2 is a single selection.
now I want if one of columns get selected the other column lock atumaticaly .
how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

set read-only property (lock/unlock) of input text inside the valueChangeLisner method. Then selection item set auto-submit true and selection control give as partial trigger of input text.